# After updating gitlab version, jekyll build reports: Configuration file: none

Tags: jekyll, gitlab-pages

After updating the gitlab version to 8.16.3, the error will be reported:

```
Configuration file: none
```

Cannot figure out why.

Thanks

Comment: you are missing this file: config/gitlab.yml

Comment: Can you give us the project URL?

Comment: Solved already, I changed the relative path into absolute path in the yml file and it works now. But I am sure the relative path worked when the gitlab wasnot updated

Comment: Might be a problem of Jekyll: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5902